# Better estimation of Homography using Kalman filter?

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, feature-detection, homography, kalman-filter

I am creating an AR application that tracks feature , calculates homography and then obtains the object's pose from 3D-2D point correspondences and use that to render any 3D Object.

I am selecting a specific area for detecting features on my source image (by masking). and then matching it with features detected on subsequent frames.Then I filter those matches and estimate Homography of the unmasked region.

The problem is lies in Homography estimation. It differs every time(very slightly, but nonetheless, differs). The effect is : Even on keeping my camera still,  I get a vibrating rectangle around my tracked region, which i draw using the estimated homography.

I have already posted a question titled        [Unstable homography estimation using ORB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789474/unstable-homography-estimation-using-orb) and got  a reassurance of a fact i was considering (not recalculating my homography if the position of the region is similar to its last position).

However, I recently came to know of the **Kalman filter**, that it gives a better estimate of the position by combining our prior knowledge with our measurement observation.

So ,after looking at various examples (one in particular, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBYW1j9lC1I), I modeled a Kalman filter(rather 4, one for every point of the rectanglular region) for my scenario:

```
m_KF1.init(4, 2, 1); 
setIdentity(m_KF2.transitionMatrix);
m_measurement1 = Mat::zeros(2,1,cv::DataType<float>::type);
m_KF1.statePre.setTo(0);
m_KF1.controlMatrix.setTo(0);

//initialzing filter 
m_KF1.statePre.at<float>(0) = m_scene_corners[1].x; //the first reading
m_KF1.statePre.at<float>(1) = m_scene_corners[1].y;
m_KF1.statePre.at<float>(2) = 0;
m_KF1.statePre.at<float>(3) = 0;

setIdentity(m_KF1.measurementMatrix);
setIdentity(m_KF1.processNoiseCov,Scalar::all(.1)) //updated at every step
setIdentity(m_KF1.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(4)); //assuming measurement error of      
                                                        //not more than 2 pixels
setIdentity(m_KF1.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(.1));
```

4 state variables (position in x, y and velocity in x,y).

2 measurement variables (position in x,y)

1 control variable (acceleration)

**following steps taken at every iteration**

```
//---First,the predicion phase , to update the internal variables-------//

// 'dt' is the time taken between the measurements

//Updating the transitionMatrix
m_KF1.transitionMatrix.at<float>(0,2) = dt;
m_KF1.transitionMatrix.at<float>(1,3) = dt;

//Updating the Control matrix
m_KF1.controlMatrix.at<float>(0,1) = (dt*dt)/2;
m_KF1.controlMatrix.at<float>(1,1) = (dt*dt)/2;
m_KF1.controlMatrix.at<float>(2,1) = dt;
m_KF1.controlMatrix.at<float>(3,1) = dt;

//Updating the processNoiseCovmatrix
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(0,0) = (dt*dt*dt*dt)/4;
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(0,2) = (dt*dt*dt)/2;
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(1,1) = (dt*dt*dt*dt)/4;
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(1,3) = (dt*dt*dt)/2;

m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(2,0) = (dt*dt*dt)/2;
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(2,2) = dt*dt;

m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(3,1) = (dt*dt*dt)/2;
m_KF1.processNoiseCov.at<float>(3,3) = dt*dt;

Mat prediction1 = m_KF1.predict();
Point2f predictPt1(prediction1.at<float>(0),prediction1.at<float>(1));

// Get the measured corner
m_measurement1.at<float>(0,0) = scene_corners[0].x;
m_measurement1.at<float>(0,1) = scene_corners[0].y;

//----Then, the correction phase which uses the predicted value and our measured value

Mat estimated = m_KF1.correct(m_measurement1);
Point2f statePt1(estimated.at<float>(0),estimated.at<float>(1));
```

This model hardly corrects my measured value

**Now My Questions are:**

1. Is Kalman filter suited for my scenario? Will it give me any better results?
2. If it is, then what's missing? am I modelling it right? Instead creating 4 filters for four points of the rectangle, should I model it in some other manner (for instance, take the 10 strongest matches based on the distance and use those as input to the filter)
3. If Kalman filter isn't suited, what else can i do to provide more stability to the estimated homography?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You are NOT tracking orb features, you are detecting them each frame. I'd better apply the filter to the *output* of the `findHomography` method to filter the actual camera position. The modeling for this would be trickier as there are some non-linearities, but doable. You can get started [here](http://campar.in.tum.de/Chair/KalmanFilter).

Answer (score 1):

This question is badly titled and after reading your explanation what you really ask is: "**Why my OpenCV Kalman filter will still leaves lots of noise?**"

Anyway your answers are:

1. Yes Kalman works for your scenario
2. You are using it wrong
3. Modify: `KF.processNoiseCov`, You can get the code from here: [Opencv kalman filter prediction without new observtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403918/opencv-kalman-filter-prediction-without-new-observtion) there is nice line explaining it.

See:

```
 setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(.005)); //adjust this for faster convergence - but higher noise
```

For what I see, you have very basic understanding of it, you can go to a naive approach and use four 2D Kalman filters, for this you can use the code here: . It will work, from there grow and adapt until you get a better understanding.

After that, you could model it more closely to your problem or you can keep using four filters, there is no "perfect" implementation so if that works for you, just go for it.