# How to use Kalman Filter to estimate a variable in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, kalman-filter

I am measuring the heading direction of an autonomous car as angle. I want to use Kalman Filter to smooth out the measurements. Currently, I can measure the angle for every camera frame but I couldn't figure out the way I can use Kalman Filter. I am struggling with the modeling, parameters etc. I am doing this thing in OpenCV.

Edit: My Work

What I did is, I found this [very related question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403918/opencv-kalman-filter-prediction-without-new-observtion/18407680). I adapted this to my code. Below is a graph myMeasurement vs. KalmanPrediction. I want to learn if there are any things that I should consider for task-specific parameters in the Kalman filter to tune it a bit to fit in my application?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to smooth each angle separably or all in one filter?

Comment: @Nuzhny probably just the angle, with "all in one" do you mean the angle generation process itself?

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem yourself and write some code? Show us what you achieved and how it differs from desired output.

Comment: @Oliort I updated question with more details.

Comment: Noise covarience parameters shold be tuned from measurement deviations of input values. If this is the graph of your own problem, than from the graph I can see your filter does its job pretty nice.

Comment: Yes the blue is my measured angles and the orange is the kalman prediction. I am a bit suspicious if the prediction was very conservative and a little slow responsing?

Comment: Try to decrease values in your noise covariance matrices. You can read here https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python  how to design Kalman filter in details.

Comment: It is a really good source. I will dig into that. Thank you @Oliort.